# bindActionCreators expected a function actionCreator for key 'ACCOUNT_LOGIN', instead received type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, redux

> bindActionCreators expected a function actionCreator for key 'ACCOUNT_LOGIN', instead received type 'string'.

I started getting this error today out of the blue for all `bindActionCreators` in the app.
I even went to older GIT history where i'm sure i wasn't having this error, and now it's there too.
The app still works, but the errors pop-up on each route change.

Anyone had this problem before? Or any idea where it could came from? I can provide more code, if bellow is not sufficient.

**Container:**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import account from '../components/account';
import * as AccountActions from '../actions/account';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    username: state.account.username,
    password: state.account.password,
    loggedIn: state.account.loggedIn,
    registred: state.account.registred,
    loading: state.account.loading,
    clientId: state.account.clientId
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(AccountActions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(account);
```

**Action:**

```
export const ACCOUNT_LOGIN = 'ACCOUNT_LOGIN';

export function login(username, password) {
    return {
      type: ACCOUNT_LOGIN,
      username,
      password,
      loggedIn: false,
      loading: false
    };
  ...
```

**Reducer:**

```
import {
  ACCOUNT_LOGIN,
} from '../actions/account';

type actionType = { type: string };

const initialState = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
  loggedIn: false,
  registred: false,
  loading: false,
  clientId: ''
};

export default function account(state = initialState, action: actionType) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACCOUNT_LOGIN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        username: action.username,
        password: action.password,
        loggedIn: action.loggedIn,
        loading: action.loading
      });
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: What if condition in action fails? What will return actioncreator?

Comment: I removed the if condition from the question. It is not the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are `export`ing a `const`ant as _ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ and then `import`ing `* as AccountActions`.

Since [v3.7.0](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/releases/tag/v3.7.0) `redux` warn about the non an *Action Creator* is not a function. See more in [the pull request](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/2279).

Try importing the necessary actions like:

```
import { login, … } from '../actions/account'
```

Anyway, for what I test, the functionality of the application should work properly but showing probably a bunch of *warns*.

---

*Not directly related tip*: You could use *action creators* directly in `connect()` method like:

```
import { login, … } from '../actions/account'

// …

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
  login,
  …
})(account);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice approach to filter imported object (with lodash), and left only functions inside of it. It helps.

```
import * as itemActions from "../actions/itemActions"; // here i have strings also
const filteredActions = _.pickBy(itemActions, _.isFunction);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    filteredActions
)(ItemContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue in a simple way. My problem was that I was exporting the action types in the action.js (where I export my action creators). So I just created another file called actionTypes.js and I put them there and import inside actions.js

The only things you have to export inside your actions are your actions creator.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {action1,action2,action3,action4} from '../actions';   


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({action1,action2,action3,action4}, dispatch);
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux 3.7.1 is just released to address this issue. PR mentioned by @Lionel T is now reverted.